# Install jss package (layout service) on content delivery server

Tags: azure, jss

I'm developing a Sitecore ssr with jss on azure using two app instances. One for content management and one for content delivery.

I installed all the jss packages on content management and it works. Now I'm trying to reproduce the same environment on content delivery.

I wanna ask you what is the best solution to install jss (or only layout service) and how to deploy jss app (just copy the file and publish content?) in content delivery server.

Comment: Are you using SIF or Sitecore Azure Toolkit to deploy your Sitecore instances in the first place? Or are you installing Sitecore manually in a IaaS environment?

Comment: i'm in a PaaS envoirment (not IaaS). 
I installed sitecore ( and so created all instance services) using azure  marketplace sitecore.
So i've 1 app service for content management and 1 app service for content delivery.

Answer (score 6):

For a CD server, you do not need to install the Infrastructure package (this contains the deployment service). Just the main JSS Server package.

As to deployment, yes you would publish the content from the CM, and deploy the JS artifacts (defaults to `/dist/AppName`) to the CD app service.

The next preview of JSS will simplify this by shipping a single server package and automatically disabling the deployment services on CDs.

Comment: I'm trying to install Server package on content delivery but i receive this error 
Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='master']

Comment: Got any further details on that error, like a stack trace? The JSS package doesn't contain any configuration references to the master db, so I'm not sure if there's some other config in play here or perhaps you're trying to import to the CD (not allowed)?

Comment: This is the [stacktrace](https://i.imgur.com/VpSqMla.png).
What do you mean for import not allowed to CD?

Comment: What I mean is that it's not allowed to use `jss deploy package` to a CD instance. Based on the stack trace it looks like your CD instance has configurations deployed to it that are referencing the `master` database in such a way as to prevent the app from running. A possible example would be that the JSS sample apps are set to use "live mode" (use master db for their content) by default. You'd need to modify the default site configs to disable this (set the db to 'web') to use in a CM/CD environment.

Comment: I bet that's the issue. By default, sample app configs come with `database="master"`. Changed it to "web" and you should be fine.

Comment: I dropped all azure instances and created new ones with fresh installation of sitecore, but nothing change.